# Do I have to prove these statements separately?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

If I proved:
$$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$$
Do I still need to prove: $$\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$$ Or the first imply the latter?

Kind regards

Comment: $$
\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_{n} = -\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (-x_{n}).
$$

Comment: True, but this needs to be proven aswell :D

Comment: But this proof seems more direct and long-term beneficial to me. Do you need help with it?

Comment: I think so. I have thought about it a litte, and this equation doesn't appear to be obvious to me.

Comment: Let's start with just $\sup$ and $\inf$.  Given a set
$$
A = \{-7, 0, 142, 5789\},
$$
let $-A = \{ -a \; : \; a \in A\}.$  What are $\sup A, \; \inf A, \sup (-A), \inf (-A)$?  What about for $A = [45, 98[$?  An $A$ unbounded on one side?

Comment: I guess that $\sup(-A)=7$, $\inf(-A)=-5789$. For the unbounded set: $\sup(A)=\infty$ and $\inf(A)=45$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94324/discussion-between-avs-and-parabolicalcoholic).

Comment: The result is false. Take $a=(1,0,1,0,...), b=(0,1,0,1,...)$. So, to answer your question, if you proved a false result then I would say that you have nothing left to prove.

Comment: Copper.hat, could you please elaborate - what do you mean?

Comment: $(a_n)_n$, $(b_n)_n \subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: He means it's not true that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$, so if you've proved  that you're finished...

Comment: The entire statement is "If $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$ exists, then $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$" Does that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is true is that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n +
\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n,$ as long as the RHS is not $\infty-\infty.$ As for the inequality in the comments,  $\sup(-A)=-\inf A$ is a general result. You just need to be a little careful with the definitions.

First, given an arbitrary set of real numbers, $A,$ define $-A=\{-a:a\in A\}$. Now, if $A$ is bounded below, let $-\infty <\alpha=\inf A.$ Then, $\alpha\le a$ for all $a\in A,$ which implies that $-\alpha\ge -a$ for all $a\in A$, which in turn means that $-\alpha$ is an upper bound for $-A$. Because of this, $-A$ has a least upper bound $\beta<\infty.$ That is, $\beta=\sup(-A).$ Then of course, $\beta\le -\alpha.$

But also $\beta\ge -a$ for all $a\in A$, so $-\beta\le a$ for all $a\in A;\ $ i.e. $-\beta$ is a lower bound for $A$, and so $-\beta\le \alpha,\ $ which is the same as $\beta\ge -\alpha.$

Conclusion: $\beta=-\alpha$ and so $\sup(-A)=-\inf A.$

The case that $A$ is not bounded below is much easier. Hint: $-A$ is not bounded above.